# Find my location with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary, location, leaflet

For my project I must to display my location on my map with a marker. I work with leaflet.
I create the var wit my Icon but I can not find how to directly display my position on the map you can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Yes and no because I don't must click on a button like "Find me"

Comment: For reference: https://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile/

Comment: There's a detailed example of this at https://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile/